# Ruby on Rails | Postgresql ignores my password in database.yml

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

Starting to develop my first Ruby on Rails app with postgresql on Ubuntu.  I have created a postgresql user with a password.  In the database.yml, I put in the postgresql username and password.

Whenever I run a rake db:migrate it executes without error no matter what I change the password to in the database.yml - even if the password field is blank.  If I change the username I get an authentication error.

How do I get Ruby on Rails database to use a password?

TIA

Comment: What does the `database.yml` file look like? Passwords in postgre work for me.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You're probably using `ident` or even `trust` authentication.  A quick synopsis of the most common authentication methods:

- `trust` - You can log in no matter what.
- `ident` - You can log in if your UNIX username is the same as the PostgreSQL username.
- `md5` - You can log in if your password (encrypted with `md5`) is correct.

**Edit:** PostgreSQL 9.0 introduced the `peer` authentication method.  From what I gather, `ident` and `peer` have the same purpose—your login is determined by your operating system username—but `ident` talks to an ident server listening on port 113, while `peer` looks up your credentials with a system call.  See http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/auth-methods.html#AUTH-IDENT

Locate your [pg_hba.conf](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/auth-pg-hba-conf.html) file, and see if you can find something that looks like this:

```
# TYPE  DATABASE    USER        CIDR-ADDRESS          METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all         all                               ident
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all         all         127.0.0.1/32          md5
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all         all         ::1/128               md5
```

When you try to connect, PostgreSQL goes through this line-by-line.  If the connection type (e.g. `local`, `host`), database, user (database user, not system user), and address all match up, it will use the given authentication method.

If you want to require a password to access your own PostgreSQL user, you could add a line like this at the **top**, before the `local  all  all  ident` line:

```
# TYPE  DATABASE    USER        CIDR-ADDRESS          METHOD
local   mydbname    myusername                        md5
```

Be sure to restart PostgreSQL after changing `pg_hba.conf`.

Comment: Very helpful, thanks. I created a project-specific DB user and found that I needed to grant `projectusername` MD5 access to the default `postgres` database as well the three Rails databases. That allows `rake db:create:all` (under Rails 3.1) to create the Rails databases. I wrote up the details [here](http://www.mcbsys.com/techblog/2011/10/set-up-postgresql-for-rails-3-1/).

Answer (score 1):

I've only barely used PostgreSQL, but I do know it has a feature called `sameuser`. If the name of the system user matches the name of the database user, the password is not required. So, if I logged into this computer with the username "matchu", and there is a user in PostgreSQL named "matchu", I could log in to that database user without additional authentication.

Could that be what's going on here?